# jQuery Table Zebra Striping with hidden rows

Tags: jquery, css, html-table, hidden

I have been using the following with no problems:

```
$("#tableid tr:even").addClass("evenClass");
```

But now I have rows in my table that are hidden which messes up the zebra striping styles. I have tried add 'is(":visible")' and things like that to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried putting the :visible before the :even?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) pseudo-selector:

```
$("#tableid tr:visible:even").addClass("evenClass");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gRyFx/1/

Comment: Thanks very much. Didn't know you could chain pseudo-selectors