# Add zebra striping but ignore hidden elements

Tags: jquery, filter, zebra-striping

I have the following code which filters a list according to what class is added to the li element. The zebra striping works fine when all items are showing but when you filter and lets say one of the list items is hidden teh zebra stripe goes out of sync. Is there a way around this?

I have checked this post but ie did not work [jQuery Table Zebra Striping with hidden rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586751/jquery-table-zebra-striping-with-hidden-rows)

Thanks.

```
//Filter
$("#local-clubs-list li:visible:even").addClass("even");

$('ul#filter a').click(function() {  
    $(this).css('outline','none');  
    $('ul#filter .current').removeClass('current');  
    $(this).parent().addClass('current');  

    var filterVal = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ','-');  

    $('ul#local-clubs-list li').each(function() {                                 
        if(!$(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {  
            $(this).fadeOut('normal').addClass('hidden');
        } else {  
            $(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
        }  

        $("#local-clubs-list li").removeClass("even");


        $("#local-clubs-list li:visible:nth-child(even)").addClass("even");
    });  


    return false;  
}); 

$('ul#filter a:eq(0)').trigger('click');
```

What I am seeing in firbug is

```
<li class="northern even">
<li class="northern">
<li class="north-dublin hidden even" style="display: none;">
<li class="northern">
<li class="northern even">
<li class="northern">
<li class="northern even">
<li class="northern">
<li class="northern even">
```

Comment: `$("#local-clubs-list li:visible:nth-child(even)").addClass("even");` should work for a selector. You'll have to remove the class and re-run this for every `li` after any which get hidden.

Comment: I can't seem to get that to work. Any code help would be much appreciated

Comment: This works as far as the initial display is concerned http://jsfiddle.net/Wp7SA/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason hidden doesn't work well and I had to add and remove classes. Here is the fonal code that works.

```
//Filter

    function zebraRows(selector, className)
    {
        $(selector).removeClass(className).addClass(className);
    }
    $('#local-clubs-list li').addClass('visible');

    $('ul#filter a').click(function() {  
        $(this).css('outline','none');  
        $('ul#filter .current').removeClass('current');  
        $(this).parent().addClass('current');  

        var filterVal = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ','-');  

        $('ul#local-clubs-list li').each(function() {                                 
            if(!$(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {  
                $(this).fadeOut('normal').addClass('hidden');
                $(this).fadeOut('normal').removeClass('visible');

            } else {  
                $(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
            }  
        });  

        $('#local-clubs-list li').removeClass('even');
        zebraRows('#local-clubs-list .visible:even', 'even');
        $('#local-clubs-list li').addClass('visible');
        return false;  
    }); 

    $('ul#filter a:eq(0)').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `even` class and then add that class again inside your filter function.

So something like

```
       $('ul#local-clubs-list li').each(function() {  
            if(!$(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {  
                $(this).fadeOut('normal').addClass('hidden');  
            } else {  
                $(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');  
            }  

         $("#local-clubs-list li").removeClass("even");
         $("#local-clubs-list li:nth-child(even)").addClass("even");

        });
```

Comment: It still adds 'even' class to hidden elements. I have updated my code with no success

Comment: How are you hiding the `li`s..?  with `display:none;`?

Answer (score 0):

I use datatables as well. Love it and Allan rocke it but I don't use the added classes for 'zebra stripes'

If your users are past IE8 you could just let CSS do it like so:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #000;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```